# How a variable arg function calls another one in python?

Tags: python

I want to wrap a variable length python function with another one. Like this example

```
def log_debug(self, message, *args_, **kwargs_):
     self.logger.debug(msg=message, arg=args_, kwargs=kwargs_)
```

How do you pass the parameters from one (log_debug) to another (debug)?

Thanks!

Comment: Which parameters? This example looks fairly complete, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Is it giving any error ?

Answer (score 0):

The method you mentioned:

```
def log_debug(self, message, *args_, **kwargs_):
     self.logger.debug(msg=message, arg=args_, kwargs=kwargs_)
```

Will actully pass all named parameters to logger.debug. There won't be any issues if definition of debug() is:

```
def logger.debug(self,**kwargs):
    pass
```

In this case, all the passed parameter(msg string, args_ list and kwargs_ disctionary) will be stored in kwargs dictionary.

---

However if you want to pass in the same format as you are receiving in log_debug. You may pass like:

```
def log_debug(self, message, *args_, **kwargs_):
     self.logger.debug(message, *args_, **kwargs_)
```